# OO JS: this value within objects

Tags: javascript, oop

http://jsfiddle.net/9nmfX/

```
var a = {
    init: function(){
        this.b.c();
    },
    b : {
        constant: 'some constant',
        c: function(){
            alert( this.constant );
        }
    }
}
a.init();
```

I have been writing JavaScript for short while now. It suddenly occurred to me that I have not been using `this`.  Writing out the entire naming for each call is quite annoying and time consuming.

In the above code is the implementation of `this` cross-browser compatible or does anyone know if I am using this incorrectly?

Comment: Read the [MDN article about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is cross browser/platform. That is part of ECMAScript, so it will work in all implementations of Javascript.

Note that `this` might not always refer to the object you want it to. Consider:

```
var func = a.b.c;
func();
```

Which calls the function referenced by `a.b.c`, but `this` will refer to the `window` object or be `null` instead of `a.b`.

Another Example:

```
setTimeout(a.init, 1000); // Throws an error and fails after 1 second
```

But:

```
setTimeout(a.init.bind(a), 1000); // Works as expected and
setTimeout(function(){ a.init(); }, 1000); // Works as expected
```

Comment: But I cannot see why you want to declare var func = a.b.c  Would the only reason be for short hand reference to the a.b.c() ?  (php seems a heck of lot more robust with regard to this sort of OO)

Comment: @John Yeah, or as an example for you :) The problem occurs more often  when the function is being passed as a callback like the analogous `setTimeout` example.

Comment: Ahh.. i see. Thanks for the tips, very much appreciated. Really starting to get into JS.. been to a few talks on modular js, looking forward to the next few years.